# How to convert existing lines to polygons with Arcobjects, preferably in C#?

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, arcgis-desktop

Does anyone know how to convert existing line geometry to polygons with arcobjects as it works with the geoprocessing tool "feature to polygon"?

Comment: A simple google search should give you examples of how to do this.

Comment: you can go through this: http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=993&t=173802.

Answer (score 3):

The [IFeatureConstruct interface](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/IFeatureConstruction_Interface/0025000002tz000000/) has several different methods for doing this.

Comment: +1 This should be the accepted answer.  Just feed the IFeatureConstruction a GeometryBag of Polyline objects, and set the ClusterTolerance really low (i.e. 0.01 if in feet).  Thanks again @KirkKuykendall!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function I use:

```
    public static IPolyline6 PolygonToPolyline(IPolygon4 inPolygon) {

        ISegmentCollection outPolyline = new PolylineClass() as ISegmentCollection;

        try {

            outPolyline.AddSegmentCollection(inPolygon as ISegmentCollection);

            // Mirror spatial reference of input
            IPolyline6 outPolyline_ = outPolyline as IPolyline6;
            outPolyline_.SpatialReference = inPolygon.SpatialReference;

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            Program.Log.Error(string.Format("Util::PolygonToPolyline - {0}", ex.Message));
            Program.Log.Error(ex.ToString());

        }

        return outPolyline as IPolyline6;

    }
```

Comment: It sounds like the opposite is what is being requested.

Comment: Thank you very much for this reply. But I think this is to transform polygon to polyline and I happen to want the opposite solution which is to transform lines to polygon.